# How to make a html scrolling table inside a div with specific column sizes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table that allows scrolling both horizontally, but even though I specify the column width in the headers, it shrinks them down to the div size.

I want it to overflow to the right, and allow scrolling.

[Here is a link to a jsfiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/ppg73nzz/1/) with something that acts like my current implementation, but here is a code snippet that runs the same code:

```css
.mainframe {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
}

.allow-scroll {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainframe">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="allow-scroll">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:200px">Long name item 1</th>
          <th style="width:300px">Even longer name item 2</th>
          <th style="width:400px">Super crazy long item 3 need more words</th>
          <th style="width:200px">Short item 4</th>
          <th style="width:300px">Somewhat long time 5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, could someone explain why the "margin 5%" doesn't work at the bottom, and what I could do about that?

Comment: I've updated your question to use Stack Snippets, which are runnable HTML/CSS/JS code blocks.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that was possible! I will look into how you did that for the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a width to the table so that it had horizontal scroll.

```
table {
    width:1400px;
}
```

A better option is to use the `table-layout`property.

```
table {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

The margin issue you are having is caused by the height on the `.mainframe` element.

Remove the `height: 200px;`

If you need the height on the `.mainframe` element and you know it will be a fixed height, you just need to decrease the height of the `.wrapper` element. You can use an exact pixel height. I used a percentage below.

```
.wrapper { height: 75%; } // This percentage looks about right.
```

Comment: Interestingly, I just tried this and found that out, but you beat me, so you get the point! Is there a better way than summing the column widths though? I was hoping for something that did it automatically. Thanks though!

Comment: Regarding the height issue of `.mainframe`: I am developing this for a mobile app, so a set height is something I am trying to work with. Any ways of working with that?